# How to solve the inequality $\frac {5x+1}{4x-1}\geq1$

Tags: inequality

Please help me solve the following inequality.

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\frac {5x+1}{4x-1}\geq1\\
> \end{eqnarray}

I have tried the following method but it is wrong. Why?

> \begin{eqnarray}
> \\\frac {5x+1}{4x-1}&\geq&1\\
> \\5x+1&\geq& 4x-1\\
> \\x &\geq& -2
> \end{eqnarray}

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Comment: What happens if $x = \frac14$, and what if $x < \frac14$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  Carlos Eugenio Thompson Pinzón has commented, we  need $\displaystyle4x-1\ne0$

**Method** $1:$
If $\displaystyle4x-1\ne0, (4x-1)^2>0$

Multiplying either sides  of $\displaystyle\frac{5x+1}{4x-1}\ge1$ by  $(4x-1)^2$

we get $\displaystyle(5x+1)(4x-1)\ge(4x-1)^2$

$\displaystyle\implies (4x-1)\{5x+1-(4x-1)\}\ge0 $

$\displaystyle\implies \left(x-\frac14\right)\{x-(-2)\}\ge0$

We know if $(x-a)(x-b)\ge0$ where $a<b$  either $x\le a$ or $x\ge b$

---

**Method** $2:$

As we know $a\ge b\implies \begin{cases} ac\ge bc &\mbox{if } c> 0 \\
ac\le bc &\mbox{if } c< 0 \end{cases}$

If $\displaystyle 4x-1>0\iff x>\frac14, \frac{5x+1}{4x-1}\ge1\implies 5x+1\ge 4x-1\iff x\ge-2$

$\displaystyle\implies x>\frac14$ is one of the solutions

If $4x-1<0\iff x<\frac14, \frac{5x+1}{4x-1}\ge1\implies 5x+1\le 4x-1\iff x\le-2$

$\displaystyle\implies x\le -2$ is the other solution

Comment: $4x-1$ must be greater then 0, it cann't be 0

Comment: The second row is not equivalent to the first one, I think

Comment: So you mean the answers are $x\ge \frac{1}{4}$ or $x\le -2$, right?

Comment: Should be $x > 1/4$ or $x \leq -2$: $(-\infty,-2] \cup (\frac{1}{4};+\infty)$

Comment: In the second row, you multiply $(4x-1)^{2}$ into the right hand side since we have to ensure that it is a positive value and the sign remains unchange. Right?

Comment: @CasperLi Yes, but as you do, you have to be extra careful about where $(4x - 1)^2 = 0$. Since the original inequality isn't valid there, neither can the solution be.

Comment: @Arthur, could you please have a look into the edited version

Comment: @labbhattacharjee for $4x-1=0$ the expression $\frac{5x+1}{4x-1}$ is not defined.  It limits to $+\infty$ if approached by the right, and to $-\infty$ if approached by the left, so $x=\frac14$ should not be part of the solution.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: $\frac{5x+1}{4x-1} \geq 1$ is equivalent to $\frac{5x+1}{4x-1} -1 \geq 0$ and $\frac{5x+1-(4x-1)}{4x-1} \geq 0$

Comment: Edit that weird "$\,-+1\,$" you wrote in the three numerators. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that multiplication/divison by negative values in inequalities reverses the sign. We do not know if "4x-1" is a non-negative number such that the sign remains constant when multiplying across - how can you ensure so?

Comment: @DonAntonio I quote from the OP "I have tried the following method but it is wrong. Why?". Aean has given a perfectly correct answer to that question.

Comment: Indeed he has, didn't notice that. I'm upvoting this answer and erasing my past comment.

Comment: Thank you all! I understand now =)

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {5x+1}{4x-1}\geq1$$
$$\frac {5x+1}{4x-1}-1\geq 0$$

$$\frac {x+2}{4x-1}\geq 0$$
$$x\in(-\infty,-2]\cup(1/4,\infty)$$

Comment: Should be $(1/4; +\infty)$ instead of $[1/4;+\infty)$, I think

Comment: user35603, why did you say [1/4, +∞) is not correct?

Comment: @CasperLi: since the initial inequality is not defined at $x=1/4$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{5x+1}{4x-1}\geq 1\Leftrightarrow \frac{5x+1}{4x-1}-1\geq 0\Leftrightarrow\frac{5x+1-(4x-1)}{4x-1}\geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{5x+1-4x+1}{4x-1}\geq 0 
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \frac{x+2}{4x-1}\geq 0
$$
Now $x+2=0 \Rightarrow x=-2$, and $4x-1=0\Rightarrow x=\frac{1}{4}$

For $x\in (-\infty, -2]$, and $x\in(\frac{1}{4}, +\infty)$, $\frac{x+2}{4x-1}\geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

You easily see that equality holds iff $x=-2$.  Then remember that $f(x)=(5x+1)/(4x-1)$ is continuous and not defined at $x=1/4$.